# How to apply mappers only to the parent and not to the resolver's return type?

Tags: typescript, graphql, graphql-codegen

In our graphql server there are essentially two types that exist in parallel.

1. The resolver return type, generated by graphql-codegen
2. The custom type existing internally before returning

The custom types are the actual entities that exist within our application before them being exposed by graphql.

### Question

Is it possible to configure graphql-codegen to type the parent parameter of a resolver with an internal type while keeping the default resolver return type?

#### Why do I want this?

In some cases, I need to limit some of the fields exposed to graphql. For example, imagine I have an internal type with some interface like:

```
interface Pet {
  petId: string;
  name: string;
  birthdate: string;
  type: 'dog' | 'fish' | 'cat';
}
```

and a graphql schema like so:

```
enum PetType {
  dog,
  fish,
  cat
}

type Pet {
  petId: String!
  name: String!
  age: Int!
  type: PetType!
}

Query {
  findPet(petId: String!): Pet
}
```

Now, for whatever reason I've decided not to expose the Pet's **birthdate** but I need to access the Pet's **birthdate** to calculate the **age**.

```
const myRootPetResolver: Query['findPet'] = async (_, args, context) => {
  const { petId } = args;
  const { database } = context;

  // fetch some data from the database
  const pet = await database.findPet(petId);

  return pet;
}

const myPetAgeResolver: PetResolver['age'] = async (parent, args, context) => {
  const { birthdate } = parent; // ❌ Error birthdate does not exist on graphql type
  const { database } = context;

  return new Date().getFullYear() - new Date(birthdate).getFullYear();
}
```

The above won't work because the **parent** type is the graphql generated type and not the internal type from that I've returned in the root resolver.

I tried with a [graphql-codegen plugin using a property called `mappers`](https://www.the-guild.dev/graphql/codegen/plugins/typescript/typescript-resolvers) which allows to override the default parent and return type of resolvers with a custom type. While this sort of solves the problem, it overrides the return type completely with the custom type.. making the generated types from the graphql schema meaningless.

Is there a way to override only the parent type without return type? `allowParentTypeOverride` looked promising but this seems to require manually indicating the parent type in each resolver.

Comment: Please I am *begging* for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)! It's hard to help when we don't even know how to reproduce the problem ourselves. You can include an online playground like codesandbox.io or stackblitz.com, but if you can the [official playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?#code/Q) is usually the best.

Comment: @caTS so you're telling me within 4 minutes of me posting my question, you had ample time to read my post, understand my examples and write your copy paste comment? 

Comment: Hey now, I wrote that comment by hand - all of my comments asking for MREs are. Basically, if I copy your code, or whatever you provide into some standalone IDE, I should be able to find the error immediately. Currently, this is not the case, and makes help really difficult for others (not just me!). As I said before, if you have an example that reproduces the problem, that would be greatly beneficial, thanks.

Comment: Just to be clear - understanding a problem is not the same as being able to see and tinker with your code. I can *see* the problem and I *know* what the problem is, and have a few hunches, but without a minimal reproducible example, I can't actually do anything about it...

Comment: I would suggest adding age to the interface and computing it there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here Charly, from The Guild, working on GraphQL Code Generator.

Have you tried enabling the `allowParentTypeOverride` option to be able to manually force the `parent` type?

[image]

Here is an example of how you would setup your resolvers:

```
import { Resolvers, UserResolvers } from '../resolvers-types'

type Email = string

interface UserModel {
  email: Email
}

const userResolvers: UserResolvers<any, UserModel> = {
  email: (parent) => {
    parent
    // ^ of type `UserModel` (not the GraphQL one)
    return ''
  }
}

const resolvers: Resolvers = {
  User: userResolvers
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer. I did notice this but it didn't seem "automatic" like the mappers and it didn't see an example on how to override the ParentType with my custom type. Do you have an example of it's use?

Comment: I update the answer with an implementation example!

Comment: Thanks, this is almost what I'm looking for. The con regarding doing this is that the "any" overrides completely the Context which contains custom types. Do you have any way to only override the parent type?

Comment: you can import for the context type from the file generated by codegen, for this looks which type the `Resolvers` type is using.

Comment: @CharlyPoly I followed your example and the typing inside the userResolver now works. However, the type of the userResolvers itself when used in the const resolvers that is typed with Resolvers is not assignable to User. So the type error is only shifted one level. Am I missing something here?